# Mesos Master UI not working via URL http://127.0.0.1:5050/

Tags: docker, marathon, mesos

I am following https://blog.couchbase.com/docker-apache-mesos-marathon/ and trying to set up a mesos marathon cluster.
all processes work fine and can see status as running except marathon...

- used virtual box to provision VM having OS as centos
- have below entries in /etc/hosts

---

```
[root@localhost lib]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
192.168.56.102 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost localhost.localdomain
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
MESOS_HOSTNAME=192.168.56.102
[root@localhost lib]#
```

---

```
[root@localhost lib]# sudo service mesos-master status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status mesos-master.service
● mesos-master.service - Mesos Master
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mesos-master.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-09-14 18:55:08 EDT; 50min ago
 Main PID: 25196 (mesos-master)
    Tasks: 21
   Memory: 9.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/mesos-master.service
           ├─25196 /usr/sbin/mesos-master --zk=zk://localhost:2181/mesos --port=5050 --log_dir=/var/log/mesos --quorum=1 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
           ├─25207 logger -p user.info -t mesos-master[25196]
           └─25208 logger -p user.err -t mesos-master[25196]

Sep 14 19:37:12 localhost.localdomain mesos-master[25208]: 2018-09-14 19:37:12,202:25196(0x7f31427fc700):ZOO_WARN@zookeeper_interest@1597: Exceeded deadline by 17ms
Sep 14 19:40:52 localhost.localdomain mesos-master[25208]: 2018-09-14 19:40:52,564:25196(0x7f31437fe700):ZOO_WARN@zookeeper_interest@1597: Exceeded deadline by 11ms
Sep 14 19:40:55 localhost.localdomain mesos-master[25208]: 2018-09-14 19:40:55,911:25196(0x7f31417fa700):ZOO_WARN@zookeeper_interest@1597: Exceeded deadline by 12ms
Sep 14 19:40:55 localhost.localdomain mesos-master[25208]: 2018-09-14 19:40:55,911:25196(0x7f31427fc700):ZOO_WARN@zookeeper_interest@1597: Exceeded deadline by 12ms
Sep 14 19:40:55 localhost.localdomain mesos-master[25208]: 2018-09-14 19:40:55,911:25196(0x7f3127fff700):ZOO_WARN@zookeeper_interest@1597: Exceeded deadline by 12ms
Sep 14 19:40:55 localhost.localdomain mesos-master[25208]: 2018-09-14 19:40:55,911:25196(0x7f31437fe700):ZOO_WARN@zookeeper_interest@1597: Exceeded deadline by 12ms
Sep 14 19:44:39 localhost.localdomain mesos-master[25208]: 2018-09-14 19:44:39,594:25196(0x7f31417fa700):ZOO_WARN@zookeeper_interest@1597: Exceeded deadline by 12ms
Sep 14 19:44:39 localhost.localdomain mesos-master[25208]: 2018-09-14 19:44:39,594:25196(0x7f3127fff700):ZOO_WARN@zookeeper_interest@1597: Exceeded deadline by 12ms
Sep 14 19:44:39 localhost.localdomain mesos-master[25208]: 2018-09-14 19:44:39,594:25196(0x7f31437fe700):ZOO_WARN@zookeeper_interest@1597: Exceeded deadline by 12ms
Sep 14 19:44:39 localhost.localdomain mesos-master[25208]: 2018-09-14 19:44:39,594:25196(0x7f31427fc700):ZOO_WARN@zookeeper_interest@1597: Exceeded deadline by 12ms
```

---

I am not sure where I am wrong.
My Linux virtual machine IP is 192.168.56.102 which I am able to login via putty as well but not able to access mesos UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by properly configuring the java. 
ENV variable for jdk home was exported